# How to set HighCharts dataGroup to a range/timeframe?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

http://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping

I can easily apply the dataGrouping of a stacked *column* chart in HighCharts/Stocks. I'm curious what the approach should be to apply the grouping to only certain years.

For instance, I have time series data and would like the data to be grouped by month, except for all the years in the 1980's which I would like to be grouped annually.

If I have time I will try and create a sample dataset, I'm currently lost in the weeds of the approach and can't find help in the documentation.

For instance, should the data be split in multiple series, if so how can it be injected in the middle of the other data points (still want the 80's to appear between the 70's monthly and 90's monthly data)? This is further complicated by the fact that the columns are stacked.

Cheers if you could follow this. A round if you could help me out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Group the data outside of `Highstock`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qsr1qzht/
2. Create another series so you could force two different data groupings. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w7sasofr/

   ```
   plotOptions: {
       column: {
         grouping: false
       }
     },
     series: [{
       type: 'column',
       data: getData(1970, 1979).concat(getData(1990, 1999)),
       dataGrouping: {
         forced: true,
         units: [
           ['month', [1]]
         ]
       },
       color: '#66f'
     }, {
       type: 'column',
       data: getData(1980, 1989),
       dataGrouping: {
         forced: true,
         units: [
           ['year', [1]]
         ]
       },
       color: '#f66'
     }]
   ```

Comment: Thanks for offering your solution, I haven't had a chance to read it or follow up with you just yet (so many other things have come up), but wanted to get back to you and let you know it's not wasted effort and is appreciated

Comment: That project has been postponed due to extenuating circumstances, so I don't know when I'll have time to evaluate what you've shown here.  Seeing as it's the only answer and the fiddle appears to show two series of different groupings, I can select it as accepted and ask any follow-ups as new questions when the time comes.